# File disappears when not ssh'd

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, tornado, vps

So I have tornado server setup on my vps running ubuntu 12.04. So when I am ssh'd into my server or am vnc'd in there the site loads static/templates files just fine. But when I exit out of ssh or terminate vnc python throws error that the file it was looking for does not exist.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I execute the server I just run the python command to run it as a background process, and once its successfully running and exit out.

I have the server running at [www.calapp.manangandhi.com](http://www.calapp.manangandhi.com)

Edit: As per the answer below I was able to figure out a way for it to work. here si the link to daemonizing tornado application, there are other ways suggested in the thread as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/python-tornado/4cxKEFsS0RE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to say that you run the server from within the ssh shell?  If so, your problem is most likely that on shutdown of the shell, the software gets a HUP and disconnects despite being in the background.  You need the software to daemonize and detach completely from the running terminal.  If you're using a toolkit, look up "starting as daemon" or launch your software from within DJB's supervise or other system-wide launcher system.